# Trying to compile tcpxtract on mac osx gives i386 symbol not found

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, compilation

I am doing some testing today and was searching for a command line program that would allow me to extract files out of tcp traffic, I seem to have found one called [tcpxtract](http://tcpxtract.sourceforge.net/), however when I try to compile it, I get the following error on `make`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_yywrap", referenced from:
      _yylex in confl.o
      _input in confl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tcpxtract] Error 1
```

What can I do to get it to compile?

I'm on a Macbook Pro Retina Early 2013 running 0SX 10.8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link with `-lfl` (the `flex` library). Make sure it's after your object files.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you guide me a little bit?

Comment: You need to add, in the linking phase of the makefile, `-lfl` to the line that builds the final executable. I can't give more details, as I don't have the source code you are working on, nor do I know what the makefile looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Makefile after running configure.  Go down to the line that says

```
LIBS = -lpcap
```

(circa line 130)

and change it to:

```
LIBS = -lpcap -ll
```

It should then build.